# why this for loop approach is so slow compared with the map approach?

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, for-loop, map-function

**I tested my code in Playground, but as the discussion points out, that Playground is debug configuration, once I put all those code in real app running, they don't make a big difference. Don't know about this debug/release thing before.**

Swift performance related question, I need to loop through the pixel offset of images, first I attempted it in this way.

```
func p1() -> [[Int]]{
    var offsets = [[Int]]()
    for row in 0..<height {
        var rowOffset = [Int]()
        for col in 0..<width {
            let offset = width * row + col
            rowOffset.append(offset)
        }
        offsets.append(rowOffset)
    }
    return offsets
}
```

But it is very slow, I searched and found some code snippet loop through offset this way:

```
func p2() -> [[Int]]{
    return (0..<height).map{ row in
        (0..<width).map { col in
            let offset = width * row + col
            return offset
        }
    }
}
```

So I tested if I use function p1 and p2 to loop through height = 128 and width = 128 image , p1 is 18 times slower than p2, why p1 is so slow compared with p2 ? also I'm wondering is there any other faster approach for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious reason why the `map` approach is faster is because `map` allocates the array capacity up front (since it knows how many elements will be in the resulting array). You can do this too in your code by calling `ary.reserveCapacity(n)` on your arrays, e.g.

```
func p1() -> [[Int]]{
    var offsets = [[Int]]()
    offsets.reserveCapacity(height) // NEW LINE
    for row in 0..<height {
        var rowOffset = [Int]()
        rowOffset.reserveCapacity(width) // NEW LINE
        for col in 0..<width {
            let offset = width * row + col
            rowOffset.append(offset)
        }
        offsets.append(rowOffset)
    }
    return offsets
}
```

Comment: Thanks, by using this it improved, but just a little bit, map still wins overwhelmingly

Comment: @XueYu Are you testing in Debug or Release configuration? The `map` version will be fast in both, because the stdlib is compiled with optimizations, but your custom version will be a lot faster in Release than in Debug.

Comment: I just do very simple test in playground, use  CACurrentMediaTime() to show the used time.

Comment: Playground is going to be in Debug configuration. Try running the same thing in an actual app that you compile in Release mode.

Comment: You're right, it's the debug vs release configuration issue. Even I put the original code in the real app running they don't make much different. I don't know about this before. Thank you so much.